# Libgdx - Textfield, show Keyboard input field

Tags: java, android, user-interface, libgdx, textfield

im implementing a Login UI for a game on Andoird. 
I use a Libgdx Textfield, but sometimes the **Android keyboard covers up the Textfield**, so the entered text cannot be read.

As solution i would like to show a **small input area at the top of the Android keyboard** like this:
[image: Keyboard input field example]

I saw an option where i replace the default keyboard by a Android Textinput Dialog, but i dont like the dialog wich pops up:

```
textfield.setOnscreenKeyboard(new TextField.OnscreenKeyboard() {
        @Override
        public void show(boolean visible) {
            //Gdx.input.setOnscreenKeyboardVisible(true);

            Gdx.input.getTextInput(new Input.TextInputListener(){
                @Override
                public void input(String text){
                    tf_pw1.setText(text);
                }

                @Override
                public void canceled(){
                    System.out.println("Cancelled.");
                }
            }, "Title", "Default text...", "Try it out.");
        }
    });
```

**Is there a build in option in libgdx i could use**, or should i implement it by myself?

Please give advice or hints, Thank you! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want to use builtin mechanism just use the **Gdx.input.getTextInput** method

```
void getTextInput(Input.TextInputListener listener,
              java.lang.String title,
              java.lang.String text,
              java.lang.String hint)
```

in following way:

```
    TextInputListener textListener = new TextInputListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void input(String input)
        {
            System.out.println(input);
        }

        @Override
        public void canceled() 
        {
            System.out.println("Aborted");
        }
    };

    Gdx.input.getTextInput(textListener, "Your login: ", "placeholder", "");
```

---

Second option is to make a normal **TextInput** and focus the camera on it by zooming and changing camera position so it will be at the top of the screen when user will touch the input - although there is always risk that you will "missed" the input and it will not zoom properly

Comment: Your answer was not exactly the answer to my question, but i like your second option. Thanks for your help! :)